# Excel formula to get numbers starting from right until reach text

Tags: excel-formula

In Microsoft Excel i have a field starting with numbers and between there are always 2 letters (different each time).

How can i get using a formula from the right of a field all the numbering until I  reach text?

After the two letters, i have only numbers in case this helps.

Thank you in advance

EXAMPLE:
Initial field: 123456FR04564
Desired result: 04564

Notice that not everytime i have the same amount of numbers at the end

Comment: Are there always 5 numbers at the end? Are the two letters always located in the same place? Is the string always the same length? This would all be useful information.

Comment: No to all. Not 5 numbers always at the end. 2 letters not always at same place and string not always has the same length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this array formula:

```
= RIGHT(A1,MATCH(FALSE,ISNUMBER(MID(A1,LEN(A1)+1-ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))),1)+0),0)-1)
```

Note this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing this formula rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

See below, working example.

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Slightly shorter:

```
= RIGHT(A1,MATCH(FALSE,ISNUMBER(RIGHT(A1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1))))+0),0)-1)
```

Comment: It works like a charm! If you have time also to explain the logic, it would be great!

Comment: @Spiris The `LEN(A1)+1-ROW(INDEX(...` generates an array, where the size is equal to the length of the string and the numbers are in reverse order, e.g. `{13;12;11...}`. `MID(A1,<that>,1)` effectively splits a 13-character long 1x1 array of strings into a 1-character long 13x1 array of strings, in reverse order, e.g. `{"4","6","5",...}`. `ISNUMBER` returns true if it is a number. `MATCH(FALSE...)` finds the first instance of where the string is not a number (i.e. is a letter). Now we have the index of the last character. `RIGHT(A1,<index of last char>-1)` returns what you want.